# Jenkins Git SSL certificate error

Tags: git, ssl, jenkins, gitlab

I'm having a hard time setting up my git repository to be used in Jenkins.

I'm getting the following error:

[SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTdiz.png)

We use GitLab in our environment.

What I've tried:

- Turning sslVerify off at System level (no error is shown, but then I receive a timeout after 10 minutes (it doesn't clone the repo))
- Downloading the gitlabs webpage certificate through Internet Explorer and placing it in the gitconfig like "sslCAinfo = C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/certificatefile.pem" (doesn't change anything)

I don't find any pages which can be of any help anymore.

Comment: Not sure how you're certificate looks like but make sure when you downloaded the cert from IE it has all the certs in the certificate chain. Root, intermediate(if any) and server cert.

Comment: If you turn sslVerify off at system level and then get a timeout after 10 minutes, examine the jenkins log for further error(s). I can't tell you the path on Windows, but Manage Jenkins -> System Log might help you.

Comment: @Misko Which logs do I need to add then?

Comment: According to google, logs should reside in: By default logs should be at %JENKINS_HOME%/jenkins.out and %JENKINS_HOME%/jenkins.err, unless customized in %JENKINS_HOME%/jenkins.xml

Comment: I found the problem. It was due to being unable to use http/s as link. We needed to use SSH. Once this was set up, everything worked fine. Thanks for the responses!

Comment: This post is already answered, Please Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45052580/jenkins-git-fatal-unable-to-access-https-url-git-ssl-certificate-probl/53993388#53993388

Answer (score 2):

Jenkins doesn't support GIT system configuration and GIT Global configuration.
In my case, I added curl-ca-bundle.crt in GIT/bin directory.

I get it from Windows GIT. 
git --version
git version 1.7.11.msysgit.0

and run below command to set https verification false.

git config --system http.sslVerify false

git config --global http.sslVerify false

Comment: Disabling security does not sound like a good solution